# Backbone.js renames objects to "child" after extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm in the process of converting all my JavaScript classes over to Backbone models. Originally, when I used the Javascript debugger in Google Chrome my object would appear as the type `DataNode`.

Here's the before code sample.

```
 var DataNode = { name: function() { return "hello world"; } };
```

After converting it to a Backbone model it now appears in the debugger as `child`.

Now the same thing done as a Backbone model.

```
 var DataNode = Backbone.Model.extend({ name: function() { return "hello world"; } });
```

When I view the variable `DataNode` chrome says it's type is `child` and not `DataNode` like before.

This is happening now for all objects extended from Backbone's Model. It's kind of pain now, because when I have a bunch of models I don't know which is which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the problem of the names of classes in JS.

What happens in fact is that your classes actually have no name at all. Your browser will try to give the object your log an appropriate name in this case. If you do nothing complicated, as you did before, that is, create a class, instantiate an object, your browser will see no class name and generally give it the name of the var containing the class.

You might have thought (or think) that:

```
var MyClass = function() {};
```

and

```
var MyClass = function MyClass() {};
```

were the same. You were wrong. The second is the only way (to my knowledge) to give your class a name. Try in both cases: `console.log((new MyClass).constructor.name)`. The first will give you an empty string, the second will give you MyClass.

Now don't be fooled. You may be thinking "I just have to set the constructor.name". Every attribute of the constructor property is protected, you can't set them yourself. So here's the problem. The way you create classes with Backbone, there's no way that I can think of to set the class name (or maybe eval, but don't.).

So what's I'm saying, is that your cause is lost. Again, I don't know everything about JS, and may be missing something.

If you're interested to learn more about the constructor property of functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can actually override the constructor property with a named function expression, as described by Dan Malcom in the [Debugging Javascript (Backbone and Marionette)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034014/4200039) question. Snippet of relevant code:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
constructor: function Product() {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
});
```

The key there is the `function Product()` part. [Here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-248) is where it happens in the extend function of the source.

Comment: Would you use `Product.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);` in a subclass of Product? Also, what would you do in a subclass of Product if Product hadn't overriden the constructor function?